# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass while calling another controller index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am a newbie to Rails so forgive if this has been answered, I might not have understood the answer to this problem.

I am trying to render the list of appointments on my home page, when I go to `/appointments`, I can the list properly but not when I am trying to render the index action in another controller.

My Static controller

```
def home
  render "appointments/index"
end
```

My Appointments controller

```
def index
   @appointments = Appointment.all
end
```

I get the following error "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"
I understand this is because @appointments in nil, but how do I fix this so that the @appointments does not remain nil.

Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render - simply render template you specify. If you want to render a template from another controller action you have to provide instance variable which that template is expecting. Here in your case that variable is @appointments.  Fetch data into this variable before rendering the template.

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

you are telling `home` action just to render the `index` view in the `appointments` directory but you are not supplying the `@appointments` required by the `index` view.

```
render "appointments/index"
```

doesn't call the `index` action inside your controller.
you can use 
`@appointments = Appointment.all` in your home action so that it will be available in your `index` view

```
def home
  @appointments = Appointment.all
  render "appointments/index"
end
```

or simply redirect to index when ever you call `home` action

```
def home
  redirect_to {controller: "appointments", action: "index"}
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried calling @appointments = Appointment.all but not sure why it dint work may be due to some faillure reason, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your Appointment table does not has any data in database. You can fix it by insert data in that model OR you can make condition to check wether the data is present or not by using `.present?`

```
def index
    if @appointments = Appointment.all.present?
        render "appointments/index"
    else
        #render no result page
    end
end
```